# How to not show errors when input value is set in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using react-hook-form, and I have two different forms in one page. I want to hide all the error messages in both form when I submit at least one of the forms, in [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validation-onblur-03cup) for example I want to hide all the error messages when I submit the email form or vis versa but it is not working, any help please?

Comment: In your onSubmit function, set all errors to false.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I couldn't find how to set them back to false, when I do `errors.fname: ""`, I get unexpected token error [demo] (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validation-onblur-03cup)

Comment: `errors.fname = ""`. You're assigning a new value, so use `=`, not `:`. If this fixes the problem I'll add my comments as answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: thanks it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the errors you need to set them to empty strings.

If you want to clear all errors when either form is submitted, set the errors to empty strings inside the `onSubmit` function:

```
const onSubmitEmail = data => {
  setInput({
    fname: "Bill",
    age: 10,
    email: "bjames@gmail.com"
  });

  // This will hide the error for First Name field
  errors.fname = "";
};
```